# How do I echo the first item in every table in a database in PHP with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I echo out the first item of **every** table in a adatabase. I know how to do it in one, but not in all. Do I have to use *mysql_list_tables()* and then get first item with *LIMIT*? I tried *mysql_list_tables()*, but it didn't work for some reason.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: mysql_list_tables() is deprecated as PHP 5.5.0

Comment: Is there a problem you are trying to solve with this? Its quite a strange requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a query to `information_schema.TABLES` (itself a table) to get a list of tables in your database. Then use that list of tables in your PHP code to drive the generation of queries to each table.

Be careful here. The notion of "first" row in a table is surprisingly fuzzy in the world of RDMSs. If you include `ORDER BY` you'll have control over it..